# Is there any way to tell when another player has given you an O-Power?

Tags: pokemon-sixth-generation

I occasionally get a message that an O-Power has expired, which is very annoying, considering that I could have been focusing on battling in the time before that, had I but known. Is there any indication that an O-Power is in effect, or that you have been given one?

Answer (score 3):

In the battling screen, there will be a scrolling bar across the top that will show what O-Power you've received and who sent it to you. You can also check active field O-Powers in the O-Power sunscreen in PSS, it will be listed on the top screen of your 3DS.